# addDocument completion handler is never called

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function adding documents to a collection in firebase. It is done using a for loop. I have a DispatchGroup and I am calling enter() at the start of each iteration of the loop. After each document has been added I want to call the completion handler of the addDocument method. In the completion handler I want to call leave() on my DispatchGroup, so that I eventually can perform a segue when all documents have been added. My problem is that the completion handler never seems to get called as the messages never get printed. I can see that the documents get added to my collection in firebase every time I run the code. Have I misunderstood something or is there something wrong with my approach? Any help would be very appreciated. A simplified example of my code looks something like this:

```
func uploadDocumentToFirebase(names: String[])
    {   
        for name in names
        {
            dispatchGroup.enter()

            collection.addDocument(data: ["name": name], completion: {error in

                print("Document: \(name) was uploaded to firebase")

                self.dispatchGroup.leave()
            })
        }
    }
```

The actual documents I'm adding have 6 fields instead of the 1 shown in my example, if that makes any difference.

Comment: This code is extremely close. Just need to add the code on what to do when the dispatch group has been totally dispatched, using `group.notify(queue: .main)`. See my answer for that an a simpler alternative.

Comment: I have tried out your suggestion and it unfortunately doesn't work. I understand how a DispatchGroup works, and calling `notifiy()` is not where my problem lies. My problem has to do with the completion handler of the firestore collections method `addDocument()` not being called. Thank you for taking the time to help though.

Comment: The code in my answer works - both examples, so it should work for your case. You state the completion handler is not being called? Is it being called with an error? I left error checking out (as in your code as well) so you may want to check that

Comment: For some reason it seems that xcode was installing an old version of my project when I tried to run it, which must have been why the completion handler code wasn't being called, as it simply didn't exist in that version. I have tried your suggestion and it looks like it works. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this - here's two. First is using a dispatch group and the second is using and index technique.

I have an array of words and want to write them to Firestore, notifying as each one is written and then when they are all written.

```
let arrayOfWords = ["boundless", "delicious", "use", "two", "describe", "hilarious"]
```

Here's the dispatch group code. We enter the group, write the data and in the completion handler, when done, leave. When all have been left group.notify is called.

```
func writeWordUsingDispatchGroup() {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    let wordCollection = self.db.collection("word_collection")

    for word in self.arrayOfWords {
        group.enter()
        let dataToWrite = ["word": word]
        wordCollection.addDocument(data: dataToWrite, completion: { error in
            print("\(word) written")
            group.leave()
        })
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("all words written")
    }
}
```

And then the index code. All this does is calculates the index of the last object in the array and then iterates over the array enumerated (so we get the index). Then when the index of the current loop matches the last index, we know we're done.

```
func writeWordsUsingIndex() {
    let wordCollection = self.db.collection("word_collection")
    let lastIndex = self.arrayOfWords.count - 1
    for (index, word) in self.arrayOfWords.enumerated() {
        let dataToWrite = ["word": word]
        wordCollection.addDocument(data: dataToWrite, completion: { error in
            print("\(word) written")

            if index == lastIndex {
                print("all words written")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Maybe you can run a completion handler so that your exits are in the same place as your group? I generally write completion handlers in situations like this this and call them where you have `self.dispatchGroup.leave()`. You can put `self.dispatchGroup.leave()` in the completion block which might help? It seems like your group has an uneven number of entry points and exit points. Organizing with a completion block might help find it?

```
completion: (@escaping (Bool) -> ()) = { (arg) in })
```

Original:

Would you mind using this setData code instead of addDcoument to see if it helps? You can add your dispatch to this code and see if it all works. If not I will keep thinking it through...

Also maybe check to make sure the input array isn't empty (just print it to console in the method).

```
     let db = Firestore.firestore()

     db.collection("your path").document("\(your document name)").setData([
         "aName": "\(name)",
         "anEmail": "\(email)",
     ]) { err in
         if let _ = err {
             print("Error writing document:")
         } else {
             print("Document successfully written!")
         }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! Unfortunately, this code seems to have the same problem as my own. As far as I understand, they're functionally the same. I know for a fact that the input list isn't empty as I have tried printing out the entire thing.

Comment: interesting, I run this code (with changes only to the data) with 0 problems. Are you sure your GoogleService-Info.plist is correct and you configured firebase in your app delegate? Have you been able to add any data at all to your firestore? Does the code work if you don't call dispatch at all?

Comment: Everytime I run the code, documents are added. I can also retrieve every single document in my collection. I should probably have clarified that I don't have any problems adding data to or retrieving from my collection. I want to be able to perform a certain action when the completion handler is called, which it seems it never is. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: OH! I didn't understand this! I thought your issue was that the documents were failing to upload, so your code never exits. I will modify my answer with some new ideas.

Comment: I tested your suggestion and it unfortunately didn't work. I don't believe the problem to be with my exit and entry points, as I tried removing any calls to enter() and leave(). The code inside the completion block still didn't execute. Thank you for putting in the effort though!

Comment: damn! Frustrating I couldn't help you solve your problem :( I wish you good luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that the completion handler never seems to get called as
>   the messages never get printed.

It seems you're not calling `completion` inside your `addDocument` method, at least for the case, when a document is successfully added.